# MVC Ajax Begin Form save and then using the ID returned after saving in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model with two entities (linked with a foreign key) and each entity has its own tab rendered using a partial view. Each tab also has its own Ajax form. When I save the entity in the first tab I now have the ID of the entity which I want to return to the two partial views in order to enable the saving of the second entity or saving updates to the first entity. I cannot get this value back to the view.

The model:

```
public class Entity1
{ 
    int ID1  { get; set; }
    [Some attributes]
    string field1 { get; set; }
}
public class Entity2
{ 
    int ID2  { get; set; }
    [Some attributes]
    string field2 { get; set; }
}
public class MyModel
{ 
    Entity1 entity1 = new Entity1()
    Entity2 entity2 = new Entity2()
}
```

The controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyModel();
    model.entity1.ID1 = 0;
    model.entity2.ID2 = 0;
    return PartialView(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
    SaveMyModel(model)
    // have tried ModelState.Clear(); here
    return PartialView(model);
}
}
```

And finally one of the two partial views

```
@model MyModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST"
        }
        ))
    {
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Entity1.field1)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Entity1.field1)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Entity1.ID1)
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit">
        Next section</button>
    </div>
    }
```

My save function either inserts or updates depending on the value of ID1.

The problem is that the values of ID1 always stays at zero and the hidden field is not refreshed on the return. I have tried single stepping through the razor refresh and the correct ID is being sent to the view.

The above is a simplification but it does encapsulate the problem.

Thank you in advance.

### UPDATE

I can get this to work if:

- I only have a single entity in my model
- I add `ModelState.Clear();` before the save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running into the same issue on my project.  The only way for me to resolve it was to not include the id when the it was 0. That way when it came back the id was replaced.  So in your example you would do the following:

```
@model MyModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST"
        }
        ))
    {
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Entity1.field1)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Entity1.field1)
    @if(Model.Entity1.ID1 !=0){
         Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Entity1.ID1)
    }
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit">
        Next section</button>
    </div>
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Alao, In the end I just used the Html.HiddenFor on its own and that worked fine.

Comment: Yea that is weird because I was using the HiddenFor and it still didn't seem to work for me.  I'm glad you figured it out though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the value from the ModelState if you intend to modify it in your POST controller action:

```
ModelState.Remove("Entity1.ID1");
```

This way you don't need to clear the entire ModelState using ModelState.Clear but only the value you are actually modifying. This way the Html helper will pick the value from your model and not the one in the ModelState.

Comment: Thanks Darin, that works nicely in my test. It doesn't work in the main application which shows that the problem is elsewhere, so I'll have to do a bit of hunting elsewhere